# Symfony - Efficient access control for (dynamic) hierarchical roles

Tags: symfony, acl, roles

I need some advice on how to handle access control for the following scenario:

- Corporation

  - Has one or many companies
  - Has one or many ROLE_CORP_ADMIN
- Company

  - Has one or many regions.
  - Has one or many ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN.
- Region:

  - Has zero or many stores.
  - Has one or many ROLE_REGION_ADMIN.
- Store:

  - Has zero or many assets.
  - Has one or many ROLE_STORE_ADMIN.
  - Has zero or many ROLE_STORE_EMPLOYEE.
  - Has zero or many ROLE_STORE_CUSTOMER (many is better).

The application should support many corporations.

My instinct is to create either a many-to-many relationship per entity for their admins (eg `region_id`, `user_id`). Depending on performance, I could go with a more denormalized table with `user_id`, `corporation_id`, `company_id`, `region_id`, and `store_id`. Then I'd create a voter class (unanimous strategy):

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
    // If SUPER_ADMIN, return ACCESS_GRANTED
    // If User in $object->getAdmins(), return ACCESS_GRANTED
    // Else, return ACCESS_DENIED
}
```

Since the permissions are hierarchical, the `getAdmins()` function will check all owners for admins as well. For instance:
`$region->getAdmins()` will also return admins for the owning company, and corporation.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Depending on how I implement the `getAdmins()` function, this approach will require at least one hit to the db every vote. Is there a "better" way to go about this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did just what I posed above, and it is working well. The voter was easy to implement per the [Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html). The many-to-many `<entity>_owners` tables work fine.

To handle the hierarchical permissions, I used cascading calls in the entities. Not elegant, not efficient, but not to bad in terms of speed. I'm sure refactor this to use a single DQL query soon, but cascading calls work for now:

```
class Store implements OwnableInterface
{
    ....

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Person")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="stores_owners",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection|Person[]
     */
    protected $owners;

    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->owners = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Returns all people who are owners of the object
     * @return ArrayCollection|Person[]
     */
    function getOwners()
    {
        $effectiveOwners = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach($this->owners as $owner){
            $effectiveOwners->add($owner);
        }

        foreach($this->getRegion()->getOwners() as $owner){
            $effectiveOwners->add($owner);
        }

        return $effectiveOwners;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the person is an owner.
     * @param Person $person
     * @return boolean
     */
    function isOwner(Person $person)
    {
        return ($this->getOwners()->contains($person));
    }

    ...

}
```

The `Region` entity would also implement `OwnableInterface` and its `getOwners()` would then call `getCompany()->getOwners()`, etc.

There were problems with `array_merge` if there were no owners (null), so the new `$effectiveOwners ArrayCollection` seems to work well.

Here is the voter. I stole most of the voter code and `OwnableInterface` and `OwnerInterface` from [KnpRadBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/blob/develop/Security/Voter/IsOwnerVoter.php):

```
use Acme\AcmeBundle\Security\OwnableInterface;
use Acme\AcmeBundle\Security\OwnerInterface;
use Acme\AcmeUserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;

class IsOwnerVoter implements VoterInterface
{

    const IS_OWNER = 'IS_OWNER';

    private $container;

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
    {
        return self::IS_OWNER === $attribute;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        if (is_object($class)) {
            $ref = new \ReflectionObject($class);

            return $ref->implementsInterface('Acme\AcmeBundle\Security\OwnableInterface');
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

            if (!$this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!$this->supportsClass($object)) {
                return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
            }

            // Is the token a super user? This will check roles, not user.
            if ( $this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') ) {
                return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }

            if (!$token->getUser() instanceof User) {
                return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
            }

            // check to see if this token is a user.
            if (!$token->getUser()->getPerson() instanceof OwnerInterface) {
                return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
            }

            // Is this person an owner?
            if ($this->isOwner($token->getUser()->getPerson(), $object)) {
                return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }

            return self::ACCESS_DENIED;
        }

        return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    private function isOwner(OwnerInterface $owner, OwnableInterface $ownable)
    {
        return $ownable->isOwner($owner);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this.one question: you used `ArrayCollection::contains` for the `isOwner` method.in order for `ArrayCollection::contains` to return true, it must contain the **same instance** of the object it's looking for.so how is this possible if you're getting the `Person` object out of the `User` object and compare it with the `Person`s in another object e.g:`Store`,whose generations is not connected.